# How to create a ASP.NET MVC web application project in VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I am using `Windows 8`, and `Visual Studio 2012`. I need to create a `ASP.NET MVC web application`. But, when i click on `Project types --> visual C#` i only see `windows store` and not `Web` (as seen in `VS 2008`).

How can i create a `MVC web application` ? Help

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using `Visual Studio Express for Windows 8`?

If so, you will also need `Visual Studio Express for Web` in order to create your MVC app.

See the different versions here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products

Answer (score 1):

u can also user WebMatrix to create aps.net mvc project 
it's free tool for asp.net from microsoft

u can get WebMatrix from here http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Answer (score 0):

During the install, there should have been options, one of which was Visual Web Developer. Make sure that was installed (that was what it was called in VS 2010).